# Background image taken from another domain

Tags: html, background, background-image

I am trying to put a code that takes my background image in an html file from another domain.
Here is an HTML snippet where I try to pull in from an external URL:

```
<div style="background-image: url(http://anotherdomain.com/images/bgimage_1.png)"></div>
```

But this is not working. I know that I should normally write this in a CSS file and put a relative path, but I haven't done that yet. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Why don't you just save the image and put it on your own site/server? Assuming it's not breaking any copyright. The other persons server may not be allowing you to access their files like this

Comment: i think your path is not correct check here http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/c29kwd8a/

Comment: Thanks for your answers but in my case it works with quotes

Comment: Andy, the other site is also mine, and in this case i need to do it exactly this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a problem, it is working when i add quotes

```
background-image: url('http://anotherdomain.com/images/bgimage_1.png');
```

Even if W3C says that quotes are optional, in this case they are mandatory.

Comment: You must use quotes when you have space in url string